# MVC5, How to duplicate Create View with previous values ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, duplicates

I have a "Create" form with its associated controller .

I wish to offer the ability for users to duplicate entry and modify the elements of their choice after the CREATE Action

My question is , how to iron the parameters in the " RedirectToAction " to duplicate data entry and provide sight to the user?

```
return RedirectToAction("Create", "SAISIE");
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Pass the ID of the object you just created - e.g. `return RedirectToAction("Create", "SAISIE", new { id = model.ID });` and in the `Create(int? ID)` method, get the data model again and copy it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Demo()
    {
        HomeModel model = (HomeModel)TempData["home"];
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Demo(HomeModel model)
    {
        //Your logic here
        TempData["home"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("Demo", "Home");
    }
```

You can pass model in TempData again to HTTPGET where you can convert TempData to Model and pass Model to view

Comment: Perfect Solution still no accepted or upvote. Lol :(